# Set "text" as default type for string in JPA?

Tags: spring, hibernate

I use Spring Boot + Spring Data + Postgresql + Kotlin in my project.

By default, JPA use varchar(255) for string fields, so I need add for all my string column     @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT").

There are any way to set TEXT for String by default when I don't add @Column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no way to do this.

You have to either use `@Lob` or `@Column(columnDefinition="TEXT")`.

More info here - https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-annotation-postgresql-text-type

Comment: Ok. Thanks :)

Maybe try to create annotation processor to add @Column(columnDefinition="TEXT")....

I hate add it manually...

Comment: still no way to achieve this?